# How to add Actionbarsherlock to android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, actionbarsherlock

I need to add `actionBarSherlock` to my android project.

I have downloaded `actionbarsherlock` and it has four folders: libs, res,src,test

I need to ask what next. like widows there is no dll or anything.

I found no help on already-asked questions about this on SO.

Comment: Just add project as `Module` in AS and add that module in your `Project`

Comment: @MD can u tell me the steps. how can i add as module. add to what first?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**  Add project as Module in your current project.  see below screen shot

[image]

**Step 2:** now after successfully adding module you can add this **Module** as dependency in your project.

For that go to **File ---> Project Structure** and you got below screen

[image]

Comment: what is the next step?

Comment: @Alex after done all the things you can access all the classes of `actiobarsherlock project`

Answer (score 0):

@M D answer is OK. But you should consider adding dependencies to your project using only Gradle. In your case you only need to add:

```
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
```

in your build.gradle